# How to feed tensor to pre-trained model in the computational graph with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a specific conditional `GAN` with some deterministic constraints at the end of my generator with `Keras` and to do so I need first to compute the embeddings of my Generator outputs with `VGG-16 pre-trained model`.

I'm using `python 3.6`.

In my computational Graph, I want to feed my Generator outputs `img` to a pre-trained VGG-16 model in order to get the embeddings.

My `img` is then a tensor of shape (None,224,224,3) since I am in the computational Graph. Thing is if i compile the following i get the error

> When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect the tensors to
>   have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 224, 224, 3)

```
self.vgg = self.build_vgg()

def build_vgg(self):
    vgg16_model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
    return Model(inputs=vgg16_model.input,outputs=vgg16_model.get_layer('fc2').output)

        #-------------------------------
    # Construct Computational Graph
    #         for Generator
    #-------------------------------

    # For the generator we freeze the critic's layers
    self.critic.trainable = False
    self.generator.trainable = True
    self.vgg.trainable = False


    # Sampled noise for input to generator
    noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))

    # Input Embedding:
    embedding = Input(shape=(self.embedding,))


    # Generate images based of noise

    img = self.generator([noise,embedding])

    # Discriminator determines validity

    valid = self.critic(img)

    # Get the embeddings from vgg-16:
    X = self.vgg.predict(img)
```

Obviously, I can't loop along the first axis since it's None index. I tried to apply a function to this 'img' tensor using the tensorflow function **'tf.map_fn'** like the following :

```
    def Embedding(self,img):
    fn = lambda x: self.vgg.predict(preprocess_input(np.expand_dims(x, axis=0))).flatten()
    embedding = tf.map_fn(fn,img,dtype=tf.float32)
    return embedding

        #-------------------------------
    # Construct Computational Graph
    #         for Generator
    #-------------------------------

    # For the generator we freeze the critic's layers
    self.critic.trainable = False
    self.generator.trainable = True
    self.vgg.trainable = False

    # Sampled noise for input to generator
    noise = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))

    # Input Embedding:
    embedding = Input(shape=(self.embedding,))


    # Generate images based of noise

    img = self.generator([noise,embedding])

    # Discriminator determines validity

    valid = self.critic(img)

    # Get the embeddings from VGG16
    X = self.Embedding(img)
```

But i get the following error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

To recap, I want to apply a `pre-trained VGG-16 model` on a `tensor` with shape (None,224,224,3) along the Batch_Size Axis (0) in the computational graph in `Keras`. What i explained to you before is what I already tried...

Does anyone have any suggestion to this ?